# Dynamically generated VFP attach to the Case : Too many Content Calls

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, pdf, blob.topdf

I have to save the Dynalmically generated PDF from VFP on the Order Object

I am trying to attach PDF in contructor call only

For the given code I am getting error :  Too many Content Calls

```
public Cls_Invoice(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        stdController.addFields(new List<String>{'Case__c'});
        caseId = ((Order__c)stdController.getRecord()).Case__c;
        orderId = stdController.getId();

        OrderProductList = [Select Id , Name, Quantity__c, Price__c,  Packaging__c, Total_Price__c, Total_Weight__c from OrderProduct__c where Order__r.Id =: orderId ];       
        count = OrderProductList.Size();

        // Insert current page as PDF attachment to the Order.        
        System.PageReference currentPage = ApexPages.currentPage();
        Blob pdfData = currentPage.getContentAsPDF();
        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        attach.ParentId = orderId;
        attach.Name = 'Invoice_'+System.now()+'.pdf';
        attach.Body = pdfData ;
        insert attach;
        //return null; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use getContentAsPDF nor do any DML statements inside your constructor. You should move that code out in a separate method that you will call explicitly. Either call the method from the `action` attribute on your VF page or via `commandbutton` etc.

Comment: can we have something like attach.Parent  = apex.CurrentPage.toBlob();

Comment: You can still call `getCurrentPage` and other methods in your constructor with the intent to only initialise your local variables, but doing `getContent` and other DML stuff need to go in another method.